# Get the type of a field in Haxe (reflection api)

Tags: reflection, haxe

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {
    private var num : Int;
}
```

I would like to know that the field has the type `Int` *regardless of the current value* which can be `null` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it at runtime without compile-time information. You can do this with either [RTTI](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-rtti.html), or with macros. RTTI would be easier to implement, albeit it might be a little slower if you'd need to parse RTTI multiple times.

Your class would then become:

```
@:rtti
class MyClass {
    private var num : Int;
}
```

and to get the field type:

```
var rtti = haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(MyClass);
for (field in rtti.fields) {
    if (field.name == "num") {
        switch (field.type) {
            case CAbstract(name, _):
                trace(name); // Int
            case _:
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to add this information manually to the class (to some magic hidden field)? XML seems to be a huge overkill.

Comment: yes, but you'd need to use macros. The easiest way would be to use a build macro ( http://haxe.org/manual/macros/build )

Comment: but you can also do the xml parsing oncee and store the result in a static field

Comment: Build macros look also promising. The documentation was kinda hidden on the page. Thanks again.

Comment: Also maybe you can do this with a normal macro and Context.typeof(otherExpr). The signature of this macro would be something like @:macro static function getDeclaredTypeOfField(class:Expr, field:String):String